# SharePoint On Premises Authorization

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-on-prem

I am building a SharePoint App for a SharePoint 2016 On Prem site. I have built many apps for SharePoint online without any issue. But I'm having issues with the Authorization on Premesis.

The SharePoint site has Oauth disabled, and the infrastructure engineer claims I should be able to user Kerberos authentication.

Is this correrct? The App Server is within the same domain as the SharePoint Server.

Comment: Is SharePoint 2017 ? or 2016

Comment: Sorry. Typo. I fixed it.

Comment: What kind of App do you develop? A SharePoint Hosted or a Provider Hosted App?

Comment: a Provider Hosted App. The issue is i think its going to require double login (login to SharePoint, then Login again to the Provider App)